# TVML catlog using TVML Templet Server installation

Tags: python, xcode, tvos, tvml

To make a TVML App I got TVML Sample Catlog from Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/samplecode/TVMLCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016505-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2 
Integrate this Catgol need Server installation by this commang 
(command specify in Readme.txt file)
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9001

This command in not respnding anything.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using http-server from npm.
It's really easy to use, only need to write:`http-serve -p 9001`

You can find more here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Answer (score 1):

It's possible there's something wrong with your python installation. 
You can also try:

```
 ruby -run -ehttpd . -p9001
```